# Prove that the algebra does not vanish and that the algebra separates

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Show that the algebra generated by {sin(x),cos(x)} does not vanish on the
set [0, 2π].  Also, show that this algebra separates over this interval.

So I know the definition of an algebra and what it means for it to not vanish for any x on interval.  However, I'm confused on how to set up this problem and this proof.  So do I put f(x)=sin(x)   and  g(x)=cos(x).  How do I go about proving that this algebra doesn't vanish on the interval [0, 2π] and that it separates over this interval?

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I understood your question: let the algebra generated by those two functions be $\;A\;$ . Now,

$$\sin x\in A\;\;\text{and}\;\;\sin\frac\pi4\neq 0\;\;\text{and not constant}$$

That "separates" I'm guessing is in the spirit of Stone-Weierstrass theorem, but we know that for **any**

$$\;x,y\in  [0\,,\,\pi]\;,\;\;\;\cos x\neq \cos y\;,\;\;\text{and for any}\;\;x,y\in [\pi,2\pi]\;,\;\;\cos x\neq\cos y$$

Observe that  " separating points $\;x,y\;$" requires a function $\;f\;$ s.t. $\;f(x)\neq f(y)\;$ . It does **not** have to be the same function for any pair of different points.

But what if for example we have $\;x,y\in \left[-\frac\pi2\,,\,\frac\pi2\right]\;$ ? Then we can choose the sine function, since we know $\;\sin x\neq \sin y\;$ for points like these.

Comment: I'm pretty confused on this.. sin(pi/4) is contained in the interval even though it's not [0,2pi]...  I haven't seen any examples on this and it's really confusing me

Comment: Apparently you're talking of an algebra of functions. That it doesn't vanish means, if I'm understanding correctly what you probably mean, that there exists at least one non-zero function in that algebra. That's the first part of the answer. For the separating thing, I think it means the algebra "separates the points", meaning: for any $\;x\in [0,2\pi]\;$ there exist $\;f,g\in A\;$ s.t. $\;f(x)=g(x)\;$ . Are you studying now the Stone - Weierstrass Theorem in advanced calculus, by any chance?

Comment: Yeah I'm in an analysis class just was exposed to the Stone Weierstrass Theorem but just the proofs and no examples so I'm trying to piece together how to apply it.. okay, so the first part makes more sense now.. thank you for that.  But the second part is still pretty unclear.. so for any x in the interval there is a f,g in A s.t. f(x)=g(x).. but you chose sin^2(pi/4)=cos(pi/4)   are they supposed to not equal? can you square our f(x) function [sin(x)]?

Comment: I messed up a litte, @user146296. I edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Since sin(x) $\in$ A, $sin^2(x)\in A$, similarly $cos^2(x)\in A$. Thus $sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) = 1 \in A$. $A$ vanishes at no point on $[0, 2\pi]$.

I am stuck on the second part..